# 'NameError' calling a function in another function

Tags: python, function

I'm still a beginner in Python. I'm working on a main script in which the function (b) needs to call another function (a) inside it but when I run it I get a 'NameError'. This is what I've done in the main script:

```
# main script
from __file_a import a
from __file_b import b

par = 'some parameters'

x = b(par)
```

This is what I've written in the b function

```
def b(some parameters):
    from __file_a import a
    
    out = a(par2)

    return out
```

I've tried to remove the call of a from b and also tried to redefine a in b but when I run the main script I still get an error "NameError: name 'a' is not defined. All the files are in the same folder and all the files are named "__functioname.py".

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is just an example name but don't name your files with trailing underscores. Secondly, is there an `__init__.py` in that folder? You need it for importing from scripts in that folder

Comment: Actually I named my functions with trailing undescores and I think this was the cause of the issue. Now I've changed the names and it works. Pep8 I suppose..